# Evaluating $\int_γ y^2 \;dx + x^2\; dy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration

In an exercise I have to evaluate:

$$\int_γ y^2 \; dx + x^2 \; dy$$

where $γ$ is the line from $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$. I solved line integrals before using $dS = \sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2 + (\frac{dy}{dt})^2} \cdot dt$. However I have never seen this particular notation before and I don't know what it means.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Write a parametric representation of the line from (1, 0) to (0, 1).  This gives you expressions for $x$, $dx$, $y$, and $dy$ in terms of $t$ and $dt$. Plug all these in and you end up with an integral that is just a regular integral in terms of $t$.

Comment: As @Graphth said. Sanity check, once you computed the value: the answer is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parametric representation of line from $(1,0)$  to $(0,1)$ is $y=-x+1, 0\leq x \leq1$, so $$\int_{\gamma}y^2dx+x^2dy=\int_1^0[(-x+1)^2-x^2]dx=0.$$

Comment: @bgins Didier's comment says it's 0.  Riemann says it's 0.  Who are you to argue with Riemann when he has a hypothesis about something or other?  Seriously, though, if you think it's nonzero, where is the mistake.  I don't see any mistakes.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed my post as well. Mea culpa!

Comment: This is a second line integrals which depends on the orientation of the curve which the function along.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it can be construed as  the following:

If $\def\i{{\bf i}}\def\j{{\bf j}}\def\vdot{{\bf\cdot}}\def\r{{\bf r}}\def\ts{\textstyle}\def\/{}{\bf F}(x,y)=M(x,y)\i+N(x,y)\j$ gives a force field, the total work done by $\bf F$ on a point moving along the curve $C$  parameterized by ${\bf r}(t), a\le t\le b$ is given by the *work integral*:
$$\tag{1}
     \eqalign{\int_C \!\!{\bf F \vdot T}\,ds=\!\int_a^b \!\!{\bf F\/}\vdot d\r =\! \int_a^b \!{\bf F\/}\vdot \r'(t) \,dt  
       = \! \!\int_a^b \Bigl[\ts M\,{dx\over dt}+N\,{dy\over dt}   \Bigr] \,dt}.
  $$
   We abbreviate the rightmost integral above as 
$$\tag{2}\int_a^b M\,dx+N\,dy.$$

To evaluate  $\int_C {\bf F \vdot T}\,ds$, where ${\bf F}(x,y) = M\i+N\j\,$:

1. Parameterize $C$: ${\bf r}(t) = x(t)\i+y(t)\j$, $a\le t\le b$.
2. In $M$ and $N$, replace $x$ with $x(t)$ and $y$ with $y(t)$.
3. From the parameterization, find $dy\over dt$ and $dx\over dt$.
4. Substituting everything into the rightmost integral in $(1)$, calculate the integral (which should by now be a normal integral in $t$) $\int_C {\bf F \vdot T}\,ds=\int_a^b M {dx}+
       N{dy}$.

In your case ${\bf F}(x,y)=x^2\i+y^2\j$, and you'll have to find a parameterization of the path $\gamma$.

Answer (score 0):

Along the line $x+y=1$ we have $dy=-dx$, so
$$\int_{\gamma}y^2dx+x^2dy=\int_1^0 \left((1-x)^2-x^2\right) dx=\int_0^1(2x-1)\,dx=\left[x^2-x\right]_0^1=0.$$

If the curve were closed, we could use [Green's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem):
$$\int_{\partial R}Ldx+Mdy=
\int_R\left(
\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-
\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}
\right)\,dx\,dy$$
while if the $1$-form $\omega=y^2dx+x^2dy$
were the [exterior derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative) $\omega=df$ of a
potential (a smooth function) or $0$-form $f(x,y)$,
then the integral would be $f(0,1)-f(1,0)$
by [Stokes' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem), which generalizes
the fundamental theorem of calculus
and has the physical interpretation of
work as a change in potential energy,
as @DavidMitra points out.
However, neither of these apply in our case.

If we view $\omega$ in stead as a vector field $\mathbf{F}=(y^2,x^2)$,
then there exists a potential $f$ so that $\mathbf{F}=\nabla f$ *iff*
$\mathbf{F}$ is conservative, i.e., iff the scalar curl of $\mathbf{F}$, $\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y}$, vanishes.
In such a case, the integral is path-independent and the result is the
difference in potential; in our case however, once again, this doesn't help,
since $\nabla\times\mathbf{F}=2(x-y)\hat{k}\ne\vec{0}$.

In our case, the path conspires with the form $\omega$ or vector field $\mathbf{F}$ to produce a vanishing result. If we integrated along line
$x+y=a\ne0,1$ from $(a,0)$ to $0,a$, we would get
$$
\int_0^a(2ax-a^2)\,dx=a\left[x^2-ax\right]_0^1=a(1-a)\ne0\,,
$$
while if we used in stead the path along the axes
from $(a,0)$ via $(0,0)$ to $(0,a)$, we would get $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$x(t)=1-t $

$y(t)=t$

with $0 \le t \le 1 $.  We have $dx=-dt$, $dy=dt$.

$\int_{\gamma} y^2+x^2 dy= \int_{0}^{1} t^2  (-dt)+(1-t)^2 dt=\int_{0}^{1} (1-2t) dt= 0 $